# xamarin unfortunately app has stopped menu item selected

Tags: asynchronous, xamarin, crash

I have a problem, when user select the save option on the menu app stops with message 'unfortunately app has stopped'

my code is like this

```
private async void Save()
{
    try
    {
        OpenWaitingDialog();
        await ...//Save to sqlite methods
        await ...//Post data to web service
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log(e);
    }
    CloseWaitingDialog();
}
```

I have no idea why app is stopping even when I use try and catch, I use WebRequest to post data to my service

```
public static async Task<string> JsonPostAsync(string url, string jsonContent)
{
        string result = string.Empty;
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = "POST";

        System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding = new  System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
        Byte[] byteArray = encoding.GetBytes(jsonContent);

        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        request.ContentType = @"application/json";
        request.Timeout = 600000;
        //More code
```

I'm using hockey app to catch all error's but this case in particular is not catching anything

The app save the data to sqlite and post the data to my service, the weird thing is that is not showing the progress dialog when it crash and happends 1/50 times

Comment: which specific line causes the crash?

Comment: i have no idea it happends when is on release mode

Comment: Monitor the device log (logcat or iOS system log) to details on the crash/termination

Comment: add logging, or just use Debug.WriteLine() statements throughout the suspect code until you isolate the line that is causing the problem.  Then try wrapping just that line in a try/catch

Comment: the method  CloseWaitingDialog(); what does exactly does

Comment: CloseWaitingDialog  = _progressDialog.Hide();